# Confusion concerning limit of a sequence

Tags: limits

Let for all integers n:

0<Un<$\frac {1}{n+1}$
and Vn=Un*n

The question is as following:
Prove that limVn=l with l$\in$]0,1].
After a few calculations I got l$\in$]0,1[ I don’t understand how can I possibly make the 1 part of the interval.Not unless if we were going to say that ]0,1[ is included in ]0,1]…[image]

Comment: En anglais, on dit "sequence", pas "suite"!

Comment: @FShrike Merci!

Comment: Be careful when you take limit of both sides of an inequality.  I believe that the inequality will no longer become strict when this is done.  Do you see why?

Comment: For example, consider $u_n = \frac{1}{n+2}$. Then the limit of $(v_n)$ is $1$.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 then shouldn’t the interval become [0,1] and not ]0,1]?

Comment: I think it would be, yes.  Try to find an example that witnesses $l=0$.